# Structure base address incrementing give different result

Tags: c, structure

Tried below code and getting different result

```
struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
void foo(struct point*);
int main()
{
    struct point p1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    foo(p1);
}
void foo(struct point p[])
{
    int a = ++(++p)->x;
    printf("%d \n",a);
}
```

When we run this code getting the output as 4 i expected it to be 3. 
As when we do

```
   int a = (++p)->x;
```

We get result as 2.

> How its happening

Comment: `int a = (++p)->x;` gives 3, not 2.  You are only initializing half of `p1`.  Your initializer is equivalent to `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`.  So `p1[1].x` is 3.  So `int a = (++p)->x;` produces 3, and `int a = ++(++p)->x;` produces 4.

Comment: Always enable and heed your compiler's warnings. (I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with `gcc`.) It would have pointed out that `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }` should be `{ { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }` [Doesn't affect your question]

Answer (score 0):

You can understand what is happening if you look at the [operator_precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) of this expression.

`++(++p)->x` is evaluated like this: `++((++p)->x)`. The end result is incrementing the value pointed to after incrementing the pointer, i.e., `(++p)->x == 3`, so `++3 == 4`.